# Using f-strings to format a boolean

Tags: python-3.x, f-string

I expect that someone has answered this, but I've searched on this topic and I can't find an answer.
Using Python3.6+, I want to format a boolean variable to a fixed width using an f-string.  I have tables of results and want a fixed width across both True and False values, so I want a formatted string width five characters wide.  The following would make sense:

```
print(f"X = {True:5s}")
```

But get:

```
ValueError: Unknown format code 's' for object of type 'bool'
```

I understand that I can force a string conversion with:

```
print(f"X = {str(True):5}")
```

But it seems odd that one can't use a format specifier code.  Is there some variant of the syntax that I am missing?  I've read [PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) but it never even mentions booleans.

Comment: Not sure this is what you want but: `print(f"X = {True!s:^5}")` or `print(f"X = {True!r:^5}")`

Comment: That works.  Please provide as an answer and I can give you credit.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious what the purpose of such storage might be.

Comment: This is the same as how it works with the `.format` method.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using [conversion flags](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

`print(f"X = {True!s:^5}")`

or

`print(f"X = {True!r:^5}")`

or

`print(f"X = {True!a:^5}")`

where `!s` calls `str()`, `!r` calls `repr()` and `!a` calls `ascii()` on the value.